# How to add Projection name, Ellipsoid, and Datum in QGIS 3 layouts

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, expression, qgis-print-layouts

I am trying to add the map CRS information to text boxes in a layout in QGIS 3 automatically so if the project crs changes the text in the map will also change.

I  can add the EPSG code to a text box using the expression [%@project_crs%] or the full details using [%@project_crs_definition%] for British National Grid this just gives the following:

EPSG:27700
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717  +x_0=400000 
+y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towes84=446.448.-125.157.542.06.0.15.0.247.0.842.-20.489 
+units=m

What i am looking for is:
EPSG:27700
British National Grid
Airy_1830
OSGB 1936

Does anyone know of a way i can use expressions within the text box properties to add this information. I can't really use python as yet (though i will be learning soon!)